# textarea hide submit button until clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a small textarea with `ID='texta'` and this has a submit button as part of the form.

How can I hide the submit button until the user clicks inside the textarea using javascript or jquery?

Comment: What exactly do you have problems with? Initially hiding the button? Attach a `click` event handler to the textarea? Select the correct elements? Showing the button? Please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hide it via css

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none"/>

$("textarea").click(function(){
$(":submit").show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vb8kr/4/

Comment: I recommend using `.blur()` instead of `.click()`, because normally I use the tab key in forms.

Comment: `:textarea` is not a valid pseudo-selector, did you mean `textarea`? In either way, it would find all textareas, and not only the requested one, so it's both further form what was asked for and less efficient. The `:submit` selector works, but will show all submit buttons, which may not be the desired outcome.

Comment: @DavidHedlund it was corrected after few seconds of posting the answer, also it was to give OP an idea without looking at the complete how could one tell how much submit buttons are there on the page/form

Comment: @3ni: then now at least it doesn't malfunction, but it may still do a whole lot of things that were not intended. `#texta` is more efficient *and* closer to the request. The same is true for `$(':submit', this.form)`

Answer (score 2):

Set the CSS `display` to `none` for the input by default:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    display : none;
}
```

Then:

```
$('#texta').on('focus', function () {
    $('input[type="submit"]').show();

    //if you want to only get the submit button for this form:
    //$(this).parents('form').find('input[type="submit"]').show();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8DnRE/

`.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7, so if you're using an older version place `.on()` with `.bind()`: http://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 1):

Initially set display of submit button to none using css.

```
<input type="button" style="display:none;" value="submit" id="submitbtn" />
```

Then in the textarea onfocus set it visible like,

$('#txtarea').on('focus', function () {
    $('#submitbtn').show();
});

**Note:** *txtarea* and *submitbtn* are the id of textarea and submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example. I hope I could understand you

http://jsfiddle.net/47Fcy/

HTML:

```
<textarea id="myTxt" name="myTxt"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="btn" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').css('display','none');
    $('#myTxt').focus(function() {
        $('#btn').fadeIn();
    });
});
```